# Caixa flutuante com CSS e HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu gostaria de saber como criar uma caixa flutuante que escurecesse a tela atrás e aparecessem informações no centro da pagina , procurei no stackoverflow br e não encontrei algo semelhante.

Queria algo tipo a opção que o uol ou a folha de são paulo usam de aviso para desativar o AdBlock.

So que não consigo copiar o código pra fazer funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc está usando algum Framework tipo Bootstrap ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Não amigo , somente html e css , você me recomendaria alguma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente são criadas duas *divs*, uma que é a responsável por escurecer o conteúdo e que fica entre o conteúdo da página e o *modal*. E a outra que vai conter as informações.

```js
function fecharModal()
{
  document.getElementById('fundo').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'none';
}

function abrirModal()
{
  document.getElementById('fundo').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#fundo {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 98;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

#modal {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="abrir" onclick="abrirModal();">abrir</a>

<div id="fundo"></div>
<div id="modal">
  <a href="#" class="fechar" onclick="fecharModal();">fechar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: beleza era isso que eu queria , so que eu consigo colocar botões de fechar e abrir essa página?

Comment: Pra isso tu precisa usar JS. Editei minha resposta com essas duas ações.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, dei a reposta pra você.